# Change of integral area elements under coordinate transformation

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods

I have an integral of the form

\begin{align}
\iint |w(\tilde{\mathbf{r}} - (\mathbf{R} - \mathbf{R}' - \mathbf{r}'))|^2|w(\mathbf{r}')|^2 \left(\frac{1}{|\tilde{\mathbf{r}}|} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\tilde{\mathbf{r}}|^2 + D^2}}\right)\text{d}^2\tilde{r}\text{d}^2r',
\end{align}

where functions $w(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R})$ are centered around $\mathbf{R}$ and their absolute squares are decreasing fastly, so that it's sufficient to integrate them over an area centered around $\mathbf{R}$ and a scale of some constant $a$. $D$ is a constant parameter. I chose the integration intervals as circles

\begin{align}
(\tilde{\mathbf{r}} - (\mathbf{R} - \mathbf{R}' - \mathbf{r}'))^2 \leq a^2,\quad (\mathbf{r}')^2\leq a^2.
\end{align}

To extinguish the singularity I also transformed $\tilde{\mathbf{r}}$ into polar coordinates, yielding

\begin{align}
\iint |w(\tilde{\mathbf{r}} - (\mathbf{R} - \mathbf{R}' - \mathbf{r}'))|^2|w(\mathbf{r}')|^2 \left(1 - \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2 + D^2}}\right)\text{d}^2\tilde{r}\text{d}^2r',
\end{align}

where $r$ is the radius coordinate of $\tilde{\mathbf{r}}$.

This is a nice integral, but I can only compute $w$ numerically and it is a very heavy computational task and that's where the problem begins.

I can define grids for integration, that are very dense around the center of those functions. And I can define the area elements for those grids using Voronoi Tesselation in cartesian coordinates. For a function, that is centered around $(0, 0)$, I could trivially choose an equidistant grid in polar coordinates and get good results, but as you can see, the functions' centers can be all over the place and shifting the coordinate system would result in the singularity coming back (at least I didn't find a way around it).

So what I need is a robust method to transform any kind of reasonable grid *and its area elements* from cartesian to polar coordinates. I included all the extra info, to make sure, that this is not an xy problem.

I have been sitting on this problem for weeks now and I'm sure, that I've gotten blind for different approaches at this point. I hope you can help me out on this one and I'm not sure if I asked the question the right way as this is my first question here.

Thank you very much.